# External css file not working in compressed folder

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the beginnings of an html web page with an external css file. It appears to work fine on my laptop, but when I zip all the files together to email it, the css code no longer displays on the web page. I believe I have the html page associated with a relative link, so I'm not sure why it's not working. All of the files are in the same folder and they display correctly on my end before zipping the folder.

Html code for external css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="AlphaOmegaCSS.css">
```

css code

```
   /*====================================================================
     Primary Background style
    ====================================================================*/
    a
    {
      color:white;
      padding:18px;
    }

/*====================================================================
 Main Body style
====================================================================*/

body
{
  background-color:#666;
  font-family:aria, georgia;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

body.main
{
  background-image:url(edit.jpg);
  background-position:99% 0%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:319px 200px;
}

/*====================================================================
 div-menu-container
====================================================================*/ 

div.menu
{
  background-color:#666;
  clear:both;
  color:white;
  margin:0px auto;
  padding:15px;
  text-align:center;
  width:56%;
}

div.container
{
  margin:0px auto;
  width:100%;
}

div.FirstPanel
{
  background-color:#777;
  color:white;
  float:left;
  height:1000px;
  padding:10px;
  width:48%;
}

div.SecondPanel
{
  background-color:#flflfl;
  color:black;
  float:left;
  height:1000px;
  padding:10px;
  width:48%;
}

div.footer
{
  background-color:#ccc;
  clear:both;
  color:white;
  padding:15px;
  width:99%;
}

/*====================================================================
 Heading styles
====================================================================*/

h1
{
  font-size:56px;
  text-align:center;
}

h2
{
  color:white;
   background-color:#ccc;
  font-size:35px;
  padding:4px;
}

h3
{
  background-color:#ccc;
  color:white;
  font-size:25px;
  padding:18px;
  text-align:center;
}

/*====================================================================
 picture styles
====================================================================*/
img
{
  padding:20px;
}

/*====================================================================
 background 2 styles
====================================================================*/
background 2
{
  background-color:white;
  font-size:32px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:10px;
  width:600px;
}

/*====================================================================
 Labeled style
====================================================================*/
labeled
{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:28px;
  width:600px;
}

/*====================================================================
 Map style
====================================================================*/
#mapLeaflet
{
  margin:20px auto;
}

/*====================================================================
 Wording style
====================================================================*/
p, li
{
  color:white;
  font-size:24px;
  padding:4px;
}

/*====================================================================
Button style
====================================================================*/

.fieldsetStyle
{
  background-color:#flflfl;
  padding-left:40px;
  width:25%;
}

.formButtonStyle
{
  background-color:#666;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:20px;
  padding:20px;
  width:400px;

}
.radioButtonStyle
{
  width:80px;
}
```

Comment: Were you trying to run the files while they were still zipped? Links will not work in a compressed html file.

Comment: The html file is failing to load the css file; you should be able to get more details about the problem from the Network panel in your browser's Inspector.

Comment: The files were still zipped. Thank you for the help. I'm glad it was a user error lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File names might change when downloading since there could be many copies of the same file. Try making sure that you refer to the same css file in your html file after downloading. But this shouldn't occur if you're using the relative path to the css file.
For example instead of an absolute path like this,

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">
```

Try to use a relative path like this,

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">
```

And to rephrase what chris said, links to a compressed file will not work.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, Upulie. However, Tengu's link to the stylesheet `href="AlphaOmegaCSS.css"` is already a relative path.